# Definite integration with unknown function f

Tags: definite-integrals

I came across this question in a practice test, but I have no idea where to even begin.

If a function $f$ is continuous on $[0, 1]$, show that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_0^1 \frac{nf(x)}{1+n^2x^2} dx = \frac{\pi}{2}f(0)$$

Any hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3899853/if-f-is-continuous-on-0-1-prove-that-lim-n-to-infty-int-01-frac

Comment: Thanks! That is the same question. I was unsuccessful in searching it.

Comment: No problem! Hope it helps